# Passing an Array of Objects to an Endpoint using Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, post, local-storage

I have a post request where the format of the data getting posted, is like this:

```
{
    "gallery": [{
        "id": 606,
        "status": 1,
        "name": "00000000606.png",
        "title": "splash.png",
        "location": "",
        "caption": "",
        "type": "image/png",
        "charset": "binary",
        "tags": "",
        "width": 2732,
        "height": 2732,
        "size": 476358,
        "embed_id": null,
        "user": 1,
        "date_uploaded": "2019-09-26T05:22:31-04:00",
        "storage_adapter": "local",
        "url": "/storage/uploads/00000000606.png",
        "thumbnail_url": "/storage/uploads/thumbs/606.png",
        "old_thumbnail_url": "/storage/uploads/thumbs/00000000606-png-160-160-true.jpg",
        "html": null
    }, {
        "id": 610,
        "status": 1,
        "name": "00000000610.png",
        "title": "icon.png",
        "location": "",
        "caption": "",
        "type": "image/png",
        "charset": "binary",
        "tags": "",
        "width": 1024,
        "height": 1024,
        "size": 274477,
        "embed_id": null,
        "user": 1,
        "date_uploaded": "2019-09-26T06:43:44-04:00",
        "storage_adapter": "local",
        "url": "/storage/uploads/00000000610.png",
        "thumbnail_url": "/storage/uploads/thumbs/610.png",
        "old_thumbnail_url": "/storage/uploads/thumbs/00000000610-png-160-160-true.jpg",
        "html": null
    }]
}
```

This then creates a gallery slide show once the data is sent.

In order to compile this array, I have firstly uploaded the images using a drag and drop feature. This uploads to a files directory endpoint and when successfully returned in the response is pushed to an array in local storage. The above data is the local storage object array. So looks fine until I try to send it back up.

Once the rest of the form is filled in, I send the form values using a post method. The data all seems to be shaped correctly, but the server responds with a 500 error.

**the error (which won't be familiar to some) as I am using Directus Headless CMS**

this error arises when posting from Postman, as I don't get much back in terms of an error message.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "message": "File not found at path: "
    },
    "code": 0,
    "class": "League\\Flysystem\\FileNotFoundException",
    "file": "/homepages/5/d755856449/htdocs/demo/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Filesystem.php",
    "line": 386
}
```

**.html**

this is the culprit in the view:

```
<label tooltip="Add images of the product here" placement="right" show-delay="500">Product Gallery<span
            class="question">?</span></label>
  <ngx-file-drop dropZoneLabel="Drop files here" (onFileDrop)="galleryFilesDropped($event)"
        (onFileOver)="fileOver($event)" (onFileLeave)="fileLeave($event)">
        <ng-template ngx-file-drop-content-tmp let-openFileSelector="openFileSelector">
            Drag &amp; Drop your Gallery Images onto Here.
            <button class="update" type="button" (click)="openFileSelector()">Browse Files</button>
        </ng-template>
  </ngx-file-drop>
  <label>Gallery Images</label>
  <div class="gallery">
     <ng-container *ngIf="!selectedGallery.length">
         <div class="no_articles">
             <img src="../../../assets/img/no_content-01.svg" alt="no-content icon">
             <p>Currently, no gallery images exist, upload them above</p>
         </div>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container *ngFor="let image of selectedGallery">
         <span>
             <img class="placeholder" [src]="imageUrl + image.url" alt="selected image thumbnail">
             <button class="delete" (click)="deleteImage()">Remove</button>
         </span>
     </ng-container>
 </div>
```

and in the **component.ts,** this is the drop and post methods

**image-drop method**

```
public galleryFilesDropped(galleryImages: NgxFileDropEntry[], imageFile) {
    this.galleryImages = galleryImages;
    for (const droppedImage of galleryImages) {
      if (droppedImage.fileEntry.isFile) {
        const imageEntry = droppedImage.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
        imageEntry.file((image: File) => {
          let reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(image);
          reader.onload = () => {
            let data = reader.result;
            let imageUpload = {
              title: image.name,
              name: image.name,
              type: image.type,
              size: image.size, data
            }
            this.configService.uploadImage(imageUpload)
            .subscribe(
              response => {
                  if (response) {
                  imageFile = response.data;
                  if (localStorage) {
                  var selectedImages;
                  if (!localStorage['selectedImages']) selectedImages = [];
                    else selectedImages = JSON.parse(localStorage['selectedImages']);
                    if (!(selectedImages instanceof Array)) selectedImages = [];
                    selectedImages.push(imageFile);
                    localStorage.setItem('selectedImages', JSON.stringify(selectedImages));
                    this.storageSubject.next(selectedImages);
                  }
                }
              }
            )
        }
      });
    } else {
      const imageEntry = droppedImage.fileEntry as FileSystemDirectoryEntry;
      console.log(droppedImage.relativePath, imageEntry)
    }
  }
}
```

**the postProduct method**

```
postProduct() {
    let productCreate = {
      product_category: this.selectedCategory, //posts fine
      product_thumbnail: this.selectedImage,//posts fine
      gallery: this.selectedGallery, <-- this doesn't send and breaks it
      product_name: this.product_name,//posts fine
      price: this.price,//posts fine
      product_description: this.product_description,//posts fine
      available_in_small: this.available_in_small,//posts fine
      available_in_medium: this.available_in_medium,//posts fine
      available_in_large: this.available_in_large,//posts fine
      available_in_extra_large: this.available_in_extra_large,//posts fine
      product_web_link: this.product_web_link,//posts fine
      ad_click: this.ad_click//posts fine
    }
    this.storeService.createProduct(productCreate)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          if (response) {
            this.product = response.data;
          }
        }
      )
}
```

I have tried setting the gallery key value to:

```
gallery: {
  data: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedImages'))
},
```

and the same problem arises. The 500 error returns unknown, but from what I have learned from working this headless CMS, it will be due to the format of the data which is causing this.

I'm all out of ideas having tried a range of different ways to get this to work and I've now exhausted my subject knowledge and power of search to find a solution. Could some clever person possibly suggest what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you need to pass in body: data, if your api handles array it should take it

Comment: Hi @joyBlanks, could you elaborate a little as to what you mean by that? Are you referring generally or are specifically suggesting we set the format of our data to:

gallery: {
        body: data: this.selectedGallery
},

?

Comment: Http 500 means server could not handle your request successfully, which does not tell too much about what has gone wrong. It could be because of format but not only that. Therefore you will need detailed stacktrace about the exception. It may be just because of date format or another error you cannot guess. So if possible please post your backend error stacktrace as well.

Comment: I am catching the error, would you like to see what the error is saying?